# Texturing for baking

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, texture-baking

I am making a complex scene and I expect baking will be only way to render it on my computer in a quite satisfying time. I read that texture has to be UV unwrapped for baking process, but it concerned some previous versions of Blender. My question is, will "smart UV unwrap" or "sphere/cube/cylinder projection" that I use frequently, allow me to use texture baking in my scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. As long as you have a good uv-map (minimal, if any overlap), you should be able to pull off a decent bake (in that regard at least).